# Solving for $X$ inside of a matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, closed-form

I'm looking for a closed form solution to the following equation:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\begin{align*}
E^* = \argmax_E \ r^T(I - \gamma (A + BE))^{-1}s
\end{align*}
$$

for fixed matrices $A, B$, vectors $r, s$ and scalar $\gamma$. $E$ is also a matrix, but is the focus of our computation and isn't "fixed" in the same way. As for shapes, $A$ is square, and $BE$ is square, but $B$ and $E$ separately are not square, $r$ and $s$ have the same dimensionality. By construction, $\lVert \gamma (A + BE) \rVert < 1$ needs to be true which I think points the quadratic in the right direction.

A first question is, of course, if $E^*$ even exists. I think it does, but I'd love help proving that.

My initial thoughts were solve for the derivative, set it to zero, and solve for $E$ (I think this derivative is right, but it would be safer to not assume so):

$$
0 = \gamma B^T ((I - \gamma(A + BE))^{-1})^T r s^T ((I - \gamma(A + BE))^{-1})^T
$$

But I started running into problems trying to collect all of the $E$ matrices together when they are embedded in the inverse.

Any  ideas?

Comment: Where is matrix $R$?

Comment: by $R$ you mean $E$?

Comment: oops, I went back and forth about representing the vector r as a capital R or a lower case r and I missed fixing the description

Comment: $\gamma$ is redundant as you just as well can include that in $A$ and $B$, and going further, you can just as well talk about $C - BE$ instead and the question then is if you can make that matrix singular, or arbitrarily close to singular, which I think would be possible generically